Real matrix rings and associative hypercomplex numbers
Are there real matrix rings which are not hypercomplex number systems? Is there a canonical form of a real matrix ring?
By a hypercomplex number system I mean a finite-dimensional, unital, associative algebra over $\mathbb{R}$  with a distinguished basis (containing $1 \in \mathbb{R}$) such that the square of each basis vector is either $-1$, $0$, or $1$. (Wikipedia drops the associativity condition.)

I didn't downvote, but I don't think this question can be answered because there is no precise notion of "hypercomplex numbers." Or if there is one you know of, you should put it in the question...

The definition on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercomplex_number) is this: "A definition of a hypercomplex number is given by Kantor & Solodovnikov (1989) as an element of a unital, but not necessarily associative or commutative, finite-dimensional algebra over the real numbers. Elements are generated with real number coefficients $(a_0,\ldots,a_n)$ for a basis ${1,i_1,\ldots,i_n}$. Where possible, it is conventional to choose the basis so that $i_k^2 \in {-1,0,1}$. A technical approach to hypercomplex numbers directs attention first to those of dimension two."

OK so do you agree that there is a question ?

So your question is “does any finite-dimensional (unitary, associative) $\mathbb{R}$-algebra admit a basis of elements whose squares are in ${-1,0,1}$?”, is it? Because if this is it, then it would be better to phrase it that way instead of using the term “hypercomplex number”.

Wikipedia does not require that last condition; it says "where possible..."

It's not clear what you mean by "real matrix ring," which could either mean a ring of the form $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ or a real subalgebra of $M_n(\mathbb{R})$; if the latter, this is the same as saying "finite-dimensional associative real algebra" (by Cayley's theorem for rings).
If that's what you're asking about, then the answer is no, and for example $\mathbb{R}[x]/x^3$ is not hypercomplex in this sense. It has no elements that square to $-1$, the only elements that square to $1$ are $\pm 1$, and the only elements that square to $0$ are the multiples of $x^2$. So $x$ can't be written as a linear combination of such elements.
As for canonical forms, we can at least say that if $A$ is a f.d. associative real algebra then the quotient $A/J(A)$ of $A$ by its Jacobson radical is semisimple, hence by the Artin-Wedderburn theorem is a finite product of matrix algebras over $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, or $\mathbb{H}$. We also have that $J(A)$ is nilpotent. So, very roughly, $A$ is an extension of a semisimple ring by a bunch of nilpotents.

This example is nice because it even refutes the weaker form of the question, “does any finite-dimensional (unitary, associative) $\mathbb{R}$-algebra admit a generating set (as an algebra) whose squares are in ${-1,0,1}$?” which might have been another possible interpretation of what OP asked.

On the other hand, if one is concerned with the whole matrix algebra $M_n(\mathbb{R}$, the answer to the question is rather trivially "yes". Concretely, one can take the basis that consists of all off-diagonal matrix units $E_{ij}$ [which all square to $0$], the identity matrix $I_n$, and the matrices $A_i=\mathrm{diag}(1,1,\ldots,-1,\ldots,-1)$, that is, $i$ copies of $1$ followed by $n-i$ copies of $-1$,  for $i=1,\ldots,n-1$ [which all square to $I_n$], since these $n$ diagonal matrices clearly form a basis in the space of all diagonal matrices.

Any matrix ring can be considered a hypercomplex number system in your definition if you amend it to allow all nilpotent elements, such that $x^n=0$, not only those which square to zero.
For instance, the matrices
$1=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$; $\epsilon=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$; $\varepsilon=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$
form a basis to generate a commutative associative unitial algebra that I would absolutely call "a hypercomplex system", but $\epsilon^2=\varepsilon$, so it does not satisfy your conditions. Yet, $\epsilon^3=0$. It is actually the same example as in the other answer, but I wanted to stress that even a system that does not satisfy your conditions, otherwise perfectly looks like a hypercomplex system (it even includes a subset isomorphic to the dual numbers).

I think $\epsilon$ and $\varepsilon$ look so much alike that they should not both be in the same formula.
